# How to specify/change the vertical ticks in the given picture?

Tags: plotting, ticks, frame

I use this code

```
p0 = Plot[0, {x, 0, 10}];
p1 = Plot[1, {x, 0, 10}];
p2 = Plot[2, {x, 0, 10}];
p3 = Plot[3, {x, 0, 10}];
p4 = Plot[4, {x, 0, 10}];
p5 = Plot[5, {x, 0, 10}];
p6 = Plot[6, {x, 0, 10}];
p7 = Plot[7, {x, 0, 10}];
p8 = Plot[8, {x, 0, 10}];
Show[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8},  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 9}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}]
```

and the result is the first plot in the picture. I want that the Ticks on the vertical axis be as in the second picture i.e. `{0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1}`; how can I do this?

I appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a lot of distinct plots and put them together using show, you could use something like:

Range[1,8] To generate the actual functions (or lines you want)

Then, just specify the ticks you want and its correspondant value (It could be a fraction or string or other things)

```
ticks = Table[{x, 
   Style[NumberForm[N[x/8, 4], {3, 2}], Black, Bold]}, {x, 
   Range[0, 8, 2]}];
```

Once the position and the TickLabels each one should have, you can just use it.

```
Plot[Range[1, 8], {x, 0, 10}, FrameTicksStyle -> Black, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, Automatic}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{ticks, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[x, 15], Style[y, 15]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black], RotateLabel -> False]
```

And your result:

[image: You can generate any other tick specification you want and the ticks will be placed in the position with the specified label as in ticks]

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like:

```
Show[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 9}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y},
  FrameTicks -> {{Table[{i, If[Mod[i, 2] == 0, Rationalize[i/4]], 
      If[Mod[i, 2] == 0, Scaled[.01], Scaled[.001]]}, {i, -1, 
      10, .5}], Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

Comment: Your code gives a mess plot; something is wrong with the code.